# I am trying to change the default promptCharacter in ngxMask in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I am using [ngxmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) in Angular to display the phone number in the following pattern:

```
(000) 000-0000
```

I set `showMaskTyped` Property to `true` to always display the mask pattern in the input which looks as the following:

```
(___) ___-____
```

I want to replace the `_` with custom value `#` so that it looks like the following:

```
(###) ###-####
```

Here is the code:

```
<input mask="(000) 000-0000" [showMaskTyped]="true">
```

Here is the live example: https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/mask-component#show-mask

What would be the best way to replace the default `_` with `#`?

Comment: can you share your code [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [placeHolderCharacter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask#:%7E:text=placeHolderCharacter%20(string)) will allow you to override the default `_`.

In your case, you will do the following:

```html
<input mask="(000) 000-0000" [showMaskTyped]="true" placeHolderCharacter="#" />
```